# Gem ImageSpec installed but not found

Tags: ruby, rubygems, dependencies

I want to use the ImageSpec gem so have the following in a file:

```
require 'imagespec'
```

but get the following load error at runtime:

```
`require': cannot load such file -- imagespec (LoadError)
```

`gem list ruby-imagespec` shows:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***
ruby-imagespec (0.3.1)
```

but `gem which ruby-imagespec` gives:

```
ERROR:  Can't find ruby library file or shared library ruby-imagespec
```

How do I require the file?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `require 'image_spec'`.  See the [init.rb file](https://github.com/andersonbrandon/ruby-imagespec/blob/master/init.rb) for the gem.